# NestJS upload file directly to dropbox

Tags: file, file-upload, streaming, nestjs, dropbox

I have route in NestJS which saving file using multer, and next send it to DropBox

The path of file is

User form -> NestJs Route -> Save file in temp folder -> Send file to dropbox from temp folder -> Delete file from temp folder

I would like to do it better, because I think maybe if 100 people upload at one time it can crash...

Have you some solutions to this problem?

Comment: If there is a rate limitation from drop box then you can implement a cron job or background queues to upload the files to dropbox

Comment: @RomanticDev have you some example or link where can I lern how to do it good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is use for multer destination a memoryStorage and i have a buffer in file object :)